# Swift generics doesn't work as expected with JSON dictionary came from Objective-C parser

Tags: objective-c, json, swift, generics

I have a function to retrieve non optional value from JSON dictionary. 
It takes 3 params: dictionary, key and default value for a case where is no value in a dictionary or value have wrong type

```
func valueFromJSONDict<T>(dict:[NSObject: AnyObject]?, key: NSObject, defaultValue: T) -> T {
    if let value = dict?[key] as? T {
        return value
    }
    return defaultValue
}
```

The problem is it always returns the default value.

```
title = valueFromJSONDict(dict, "title", "")
```

but if I do same thing without generics it works fine:

```
title = { () -> String 
   if let value = dict?["title"] as? String {
      title = value
   } else {
      return ""
   }
}()
```

This parsed JSON dict is coming from Objective-C parser and if I `println` `dynamicType` of value from the dict is like `__CFNSString`, but `T.self` is `Swift.String`, so Swift is unable to figure out types probably

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

What does your `dict` object look like?

Here is what I would suggest:

```
typealias JSONObject = [String: AnyObject]

func valueFromJSON<T>(json: JSONObject?, key: String, defaultValue: T) -> T
{
    if let value = json?[key] as? T {
        return value
    }
    return defaultValue
}

let json = ["Name": "Sir Lancelot",
            "Quest": "To seek the Holy Grail",
            "Favorite Color": "Blue..."]

let name = valueFromJSON(json, "Name", "Sir Not Appearing In This Film")
```

Comment: Good suggestion about code-style, I'll definitely use it. But the key type doesn't make sense here. I think the problem is that JSON coming from Objective-C parser, so Swift is unable to figure out the types normally

Comment: You may be right, but it is difficult to test without knowing the contents of your `dict`. Also, I recommend using the Swift types as much as possible (`String`, `Int`, `Float`, ...) instead of the Obj-C counterparts. I think Swift has better casting/bridging logic with its own native types.

Comment: agreed, but this dict is coming from AFNetworking which is Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered, that method actually **work is I assign the result to some var or let**:

```
let value = valueFromJSONDict(dict, "title", "") // value from JSON
```

but **didn't work if I assign the result to a property**:

```
title = valueFromJSONDict(dict, "title", "") // always ""
```

So finally **I've fixed this issue by replacing my property type from non-optional** `@NSManaged var title: String` **to implicitly unwrapped optional** `@NSManaged var title: String!`